# Creating a styled result-only google costume search with my own searchbox

Tags: html, css, forms, search

I have been working on the google's costume search feature for the past two days,And frankly,I am completely lost!
I have a search-box which is styled the way that matches my websites looks,and now I want to deploy google's costume search on it AND I want the search result to appear in a different page(e.g `searchresult.aspx`) and I want the result to be in a `<div>` in my page(I want to position the `div` I am talking about)

let me show you my codes:

```
//this is my form:
<form id="searchBox" action="/" dir="rtl">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search...." />
</form>
//this is the css:
#searchBox
{
position: absolute;
right: 760px;
top: 15px;
}

#searchBox input[type="text"]
{
    background: url(../PNGs/sbDark.png) no-repeat 10px 10px #444;
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: bkoodak;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease ;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease ;
    transition: all 0.2s ease ;
}

#searchBox input[type="text"]:focus
{
outline: none;
background: url(../PNGs/sbWhite.png) no-repeat 10px 10px #fcfcfc;
padding-right: 15px;
color: #333333;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

//I want the result page to be something like this:
<body>
    <!-- other parts of the page-->
    <div id=searchresult>
        <!-- this is where I want the search result to appear-->
    </div>
    <!--other parts of the page-->
</body>
```

So far,I made a test costume search on google,chose the result-only layout(because it said I can make my own search box for it AND I can put the results in a different page),and added some color to it using the control panel provided.But the generated code was no different than the code of the default layout.And now I don't know how can I use it

I did look here and there in some blogs for something,But none of them were the thing I wanted!For example I have found this code:

```
<form id="searchbox_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYY" action="URL of the Page where the Result is to be shown"> 
  <input value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYY" name="cx" type="hidden"/> 
  <input value="FORID:11" name="cof" type="hidden"/> 
  <input id="q" style="width:150px;" name="q" size="70" type="text" /> 
  <input value="Search" name="sa" type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

where `xxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyyy` is my search id.So I just created a form like above(and didn't included the script from google),but it just wouldn't show me anything

Long story short,I want something like [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/) 's work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out.With result only layout selected,I could enter my own search parameter(the default value is q)
then in my search box I entered:

```
<form id="searchBox" action="search_result.aspx" dir="rtl">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search...." />
```

and then,in my result page, I pasted the google's generated script in the `div` I wanted,like this:

```
<body>
<!-- other parts of the page-->
<div id=searchresult>
    <!-- google's script-->
</div>
<!--other parts of the page-->
</body>
```